# Find the mean value of close rate for the year and company name in R

Tags: sql, r, group-by, statistics, aggregate

Below is a  sample of my dataset, I need to find the mean of Close rate  of a  company for a year.

```
Date    Close   company
2008    49.220001   Allstate Insurance Group
2008    47.73   Allstate Insurance Group
2008    48.060001   Allstate Insurance Group
2008    50.360001   Allstate Insurance Group
2009    21.67   Allstate Insurance Group
2009    16.83   Allstate Insurance Group
2011    31.139999   Allstate Insurance Group
2011    31.780001   Allstate Insurance Group
2011    31.780001   Allstate Insurance Group
2008    42.130001   ANTHEM
2009    41.450001   ANTHEM
2009    33.919998   ANTHEM
2009    37.970001   ANTHEM
2010    48.93   ANTHEM
2010    50.720001   ANTHEM
2010    49.66   ANTHEM
2012    18.219999   AXA inaurance
2013    18.450001   AXA inaurance
2014    26.309999   AXA inaurance
2014    25.950001   AXA inaurance
```

Now i need to find the mean value of each company for every year. For example i need to find mean value of "ANTHEM" for every year "2008, 2009, 2010". not sure how to pass 2 variables in aggregate function.

My expected output is:

```
2008    42.130001   ANTHEM
2009    37.6849995  ANTHEM
2010    49.77000033 ANTHEM
2008    48.84250075 Allstate Insurance Group
2009    19.25   Allstate Insurance Group
2011    31.566667   Allstate Insurance Group
```

Comment: How about `aggregate(Close ~ ., df1, mean)`

Answer (score 1):

just use `avg()`

```
select date,company, avg(close)
from table group by date,company
```